# Setting iface mapCanvas extent

Tags: pyqgis, extents, qgsmapcanvas

How to set map canvas extent / view?
I've tried with `setExtent(Qrect(..))` but does not work.

```py
mc = iface.mapCanvas()
rect = QgsRectangle()
rect.setXMaximum = 5
rect.setXMinimum = 2
rect.setYMaximum = 10
rect.setYMinimum = 3
mc.setExtent(rect)
```

Comment: Your code works for me, maybe try to set an extent of a layer as `rect`, to see if it really works or not. Like this `layer = iface.activeLayer() ; rect = layer.extent() ; iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(rect); ` and add a `iface.mapCanvas().refresh()` at the end of your code to refresh the resolution.

Comment: Your code work. The the layer fit with the canvas area. But with my code no, the object become very small and out of canvas view.

Comment: What CRS are you using in your project ?

Comment: I'm using EPSG:4326

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
mc=iface.mapCanvas()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
geocella=layers[0]
features= geocella.getFeatures()
basepath =  "C:/Users/user/Desktop/export_maps_QGIS/OUT"

i = 0
for ftr in features:
    name = ftr['name']
    print("Name:")
    print(name)
    bb = ftr.geometry().boundingBox()
    xmax = bb.xMaximum()
    xmin = bb.xMinimum()
    ymax = bb.yMaximum()
    ymin = bb.yMinimum()
    rect = QgsRectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
    rect.setXMaximum = xmax
    rect.setxMinimum = xmin
    rect.setyMaximum = ymax
    rect.setyMinimum = ymin
    
    iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(rect)

    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    
    mc.setExtent(rect)
    settings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
    settings.setOutputSize(QSize(1000, 1000))
    settings.setExtent(rect)
    settings.setFlag(QgsMapSettings.DrawLabeling, False)
    settings.setFlag(QgsMapSettings.Antialiasing, True)

    job = QgsMapRendererSequentialJob(settings)
    job.start()
    job.waitForFinished()
    image = job.renderedImage()

    filepath = os.path.join(basepath, "out" + str(i) + ".tif")
    image.save(filepath)
    i = i + 1
```